# EF turned bigint column to int32 in metadata file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, metadata

For a table *SomeTable* in my database, EF converted the primary key of type *bigint* to a property of type *int32* in metadata file, whereas its equivalent, model-generated partial class has datatype of *long* for the same field. This creates a conflict when I try to load data from *SomeTable*. Following exception is thrown at runtime...

```
System.MissingMethodException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233069
  Message=Method not found: 'Int32 RMSDataLibrary.SomeTable.get_ID()'.
  Source=GUI_Forms
  StackTrace:
       at GUI_Forms.DataRetrieval.populateData()
       at GUI_Forms.DataRetrieval.DataRetrieval_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\RMS\C#\RMS-ESS\GUI_Forms\DataRetrieval.cs:line 25
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
  InnerException:
```

I am unable to modify the metadata file to correct the datatype. Why could possibly this conflict have been created? and any solution for that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it's not the EF but our DB guy who changed the primary key's datatype from *int* to *bigint* :) but somehow deleting that table from my .edmx and then updating the model was not bringing any changes to the metadata file (EF bug???) Even deleting all the contents of .edmx and updating was not having any effect.

Frustrated enough, I removed the whole ADO.NET EF Data Model folder that I had created and then re-created the same from scratch. And it resolved the problem.

I think either EF should update metadata file when updating .edmx file or it should allow the programmer to change it.